# Adding members to interfaces declared in a module

Tags: typescript, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm trying to use the Bootstrap Datetimepicker plugin in my TypeScript code. I've downloaded the .d.ts definitions for the plugin, but taht one does not include currently the method `Datetimepicker.destroy`. However, it's present in the plugin, so I would like to use it with type safety.

Normally I would do a simple interface (extension) on my root level like this:

```
inteface Datetimepicker {
  destroy():void;
}
```

But in this case it does not work, because the `Datetimepicker` interface is defined within a `BootstrapV3DatetimePicker` module in the d.ts file, so this kind of extension doesn't work. I tried this way also:

```
module BootstrapV3DatetimePicker { 
  inteface Datetimepicker {
    destroy():void;
  }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work either, the destroy method is still nto recognized by Visual Studio.

How to add new members to an existing interface if it's defined within a module in an external d.ts file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try :

```
  declare module BootstrapV3DatetimePicker { 
     export inteface Datetimepicker {
       destroy():void;
    }
 }
```

Notice the export and declare

Comment: Thank you, I've only needed the export keyword, and it works perfectly without the declare too. Does declare have an intended role in your answer?

Comment: you need it the function doesn't have a body ... without `declare` JavaScript is generated